# How to enable PurgeCSS for 3rd-part CSS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, css-purge

I am using [@mdi/font](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign) in my SSR Nuxt project.

How can I enable purgeCSS for CSS from [@mdi/font](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign)?

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    css: [
        '@/assets/scss/app.scss'
    ],
    ...
}
```

**assets/scss/app.scss**

```
@import '~@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons';
```

I try to config like below, but it just remove all the css
(example from [purgecss.com](https://purgecss.com/guides/nuxt.html#nuxt-js-plugin))

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    build: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: {
                '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss': {
                    content: ['./pages/**/*.vue', './layouts/**/*.vue', './components/**/*.vue'],
                    whitelist: ['html', 'body']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using [nuxt-purgecss](https://github.com/Developmint/nuxt-purgecss)

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    buildModules: [
        'nuxt-purgecss'
    ]
}
```